# Add Star to likes using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi Following coding i have created to rating star.

```
<body>
<button id="onestar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"  onclick="ratingFunction('1')"></span></button>
                                      <button id="onestarfill" hidden><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:yellow" id="onestar" onclick="ratingFunction('1')" ></span></button>
                                      <button id="twostar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" id="twostar" onclick="ratingFunction('2')"></span></button>
                                      <button id="twostarfill" hidden><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" style="color: yellow" id="twostar" onclick="ratingFunction('2')" hidden></span></button>
                                      <button id="threestar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" id="threestar" onclick="ratingFunction('3')"></span></button>
                                      <button id="threestarfill" hidden><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" style="color: yellow"id="threestar" onclick="ratingFunction('3')" hidden></span></button>
                                      <button id="fourstar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" id="fourstar" onclick="ratingFunction('4')"></span></button>
                                      <button id="fourstarfill" hidden><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" style="color: yellow"id="fourstar" onclick="ratingFunction('4')" hidden></span></button>
                                      <button id="fivestar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" id="fivestar" onclick="ratingFunction('5')"></span></button>
                                      <button id="fivestarfill" hidden><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" style="color: yellow"id="fivestar" onclick="ratingFunction('5')" hidden></span></button>
<script>
function ratingFunction(intValue){
    var finder_id=<?php echo $rowpic['f_id']?>;
    var user_id="<?php echo $_SESSION['Uid'];?>";//document.getElementById("#user_id_of_rater").value;
    var action='rate_to_finder';
    var rate=intValue;

   if(intValue=='1')
   {
       $.post('db/db_add_star_rate.php',{'user_id':user_id ,'action':action, 'rate':rate,'finder_id':finder_id},function(data){
             alert(data);
             });
       $("#onestar").hide();
       $("#onestarfill").show();


   }
   else if(intValue=='2')
   {
       $.post('db/db_add_star_rate.php',{'user_id':user_id ,'action':action, 'rate':rate,'finder_id':finder_id},function(data){
             alert(data);
             });
       $("#twostar").hide();
       $("#twostarfill").show();

   }
   else if(intValue=='3')
   {
       $.post('db/db_add_star_rate.php',{'user_id':user_id ,'action':action, 'rate':rate,'finder_id':finder_id},function(data){
             alert(data);
             });
       $("#threestar").hide();
       $("#threestarfill").show();
   }
   else if(intValue=='4')
 ........
}
</script>
</body>
```

so i want to when i click on id='threestar', then it shod hide following ids onestar, twostar and threestar. And should show onestarfil, twostarfil and threestarfil. how can i do this.

Comment: i have tried like
`else if(intValue=='3')
   {
 ...............
       $("#threestar ,#thowstar, #onestar ").hide();
       $("#threestarfill,,#thowstarfill , #onestarfill").show();
   }`
but it's not working

Comment: So much copy and pasting. That is a bad design. There is no need to copy and paste so much because you can use variables and use that in one Ajax call. Why don't you jut switch classes and not show/hide elements?

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea without all of the ifs and else and no need for multiple buttons for each state.

```js
$(".stars").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(this)  //the button that was clicked
    .prevAll("button")  //find previous buttons
    .addBack()  //add in the button that was clicked
      .find("span")  //find the spans in the butto
          .addClass("glyphicon-star")  //check the star
          .removeClass("glyphicon-star-empty");  //uncheck the star
  $(this)
    .nextAll("button")
      .find("span")
          .removeClass("glyphicon-star")
          .addClass("glyphicon-star-empty");
  
  console.log(this.value);  //the value of the star that was selected
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="stars">
  <button value="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  </button>
  <button value="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  </button>
  <button value="3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  </button>
  <button value="4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  </button>
  <button value="5"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```